# What regiment do soldiers under Dhalis Zachary's belong to?

Tags: attack-on-titan

Their uniforms are different from the scouts,garrison and military police as shown in the scene when they stage the coup. Are they Dhalis Zachary's personal guard ?

[image: Soldiers during coup]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dhalis Zachary is the leader of all the military regiments. All regiments (Scouts, Garrison and Military) have a leader and they directly answer to him.

So as you can guess he and his soldiers don't belong to any regiment but they answer directly to him.

Comment: Hence a plain checked uniform for the soldiers (without the rose,horse or wings ) ...?

Comment: @asdf Yes. You can think of their uniform as a parent and others as children.